# No Wifi available after a fresh Win 7 install

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, thinkpad

I just installed Win 7 Home Premium on a ThinkPad E420, and the wifi isn't working. I've done all the Windows Updates, and I have a wired connection, but I am totally stumped here-I'm definitely not a Windows person, so I am sorta clueless. Can someone help walk me through this? In the device manager, it says I have no network controller or base system device. I've installed some wireless drivers from the support.lenovo.com site, but that has done nothing. Help!

netsh interface ip show interfaces results:

```
 Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
 ---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
 1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 11          10        1500  connected     Local Area Connection
```

Ipconfig results:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::da0:e4f6:7801:2ea6%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.19
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.{1A0CC728-21C5-4A94-8A6B-7E888650D995}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:14d6:2ddb:f5fe:f5ec
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14d6:2ddb:f5fe:f5ec%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

Comment: Is there a hardware switch on your notebook, to toggle WiFi? Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `cmd`. In the newly opened shell enter `ipconfig`; what does it say?

Comment: I added ipconfig results above

Comment: Also, I checked the bios, wifi is enabled there.

Comment: You said, you're not a Windows person, did it work on Linux? If your Ethernet (cable) connection works, you could try to download a Linux live system (Knoppix, Ubuntu, etc.) and check if your wireless adapter runs on the Linux live system. In Linux open a Shell/Terminal and enter `rfkill list` and look for a "Wireless Lan" device it has to be neither 'Soft blocked' nor 'Hard blocked'. `ifconfig -a` is a way too, to identify the installed devices. If there is no Wireless device listed on Linux, it could be defect. If you don't have the time to or it is broken, better contact the Lenovo support.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help for you: [http://superuser.com/questions/619786/use-commandline-to-show-disabled-network-interfaces-in-windows-mobile-broadban](http://superuser.com/questions/619786/use-commandline-to-show-disabled-network-interfaces-in-windows-mobile-broadban)

Comment: `netsh mbn show interfaces` Does this show anything else than `netsh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution
http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-73695
I downloaded and installed this, and it seems to work. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: feel free to accept your own answer so that this shows up as answered, it's a standard thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [install the latest wireless drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS015008). Next, [check out this link](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-Knowledge-Base/Is-there-a-wifi-switch-on-Thinkpad-E420-or-E520-Edge/ta-p/626145) for instructions on turning on WiFi on your laptop. If that doesn't work, try rebooting and repeat those steps, then check in Device Manager to see if the device is at least showing up.